# prove $f\left(A∩\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=f\left(A\right)\ ∩\ B$ and $f\left(\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=f\left(X\right)\ ∩\ B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Assume $f:\ X→Y$ and $A⊆X\ ,\ B⊆Y$ then prove:

$$f\left(A∩\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=f\left(A\right)\ ∩\ B$$

$$f\left(\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=f\left(X\right)\ ∩\ B$$

For the first one assume $y\ ∈\ f\left(A∩\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$, iff there exist $x\ ∈\left(A∩\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$ such that $f(x)=y$ , in other words there exist 
$x$$\ ∈\ A$ such that $f(x)=y$ and there exist $x$$\ ∈f^{-1}\left(B\right)$ such that $f(x)=y$, implies $y\ ∈\ f\left(A\right)\ \text{and}\ f\left(x\right)=y\ ∈\ B$

For the other one 
let $y\ ∈\ f\left(\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)$ this holds iff $\ ∃\ x\ ∈\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)$ such that $f\left(x\right)=y$ or equivalently $\ ∃f\left(x\right)\ ∈B$ such that $\ f\left(x\right)=y$ hence $\ y∈\ \ B$

Comment: The quatifier $\exists$ does not distribute over logical conjunction $\land$: id est, the sentence "$\exists x, P\land Q$" is not equivalent to "$(\exists x, P)\land (\exists x, Q)$". See "there is a natural number which is odd and even" versus "there is a natural number which is even and there is a natural number which is odd".

Comment: that's true, thanks

Comment: Well for the first one you've only proven that $f\left(A∩\ f^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)⊆f\left(A\right)\ ∩\ B$ Proving two sets are equal requires you to prove that both sets contain each other.

Answer (score 1):

You've only done one inclusion: $$f[A \cap f^{-1}[B]] \subseteq f[A]\cap B$$

(I use brackets $[]$ for the *set* (inverse) images of functions, and parentheses $()$ for evaluations of elements of the domain).

You also need the reverse inclusion for equality of sets: if $y \in f[A] \cap B$, so we know $y \in B$ and there is some $x \in A$ with $f(x)=y$. Then $x \in f^{-1}[B]$ by definition (its image is in $B$) so $x \in A \cap f^{-1}[B]$ and as $y=f(x)$, so we know $y \in f[A \cap f^{-1}[B]]$, as required.

Likewise your second proof shows

$$f[f^{-1}[B]] \subseteq f[X] \cap B$$ and we again also need the reverse inclusion: if $y \in f[X] \cap B$, so we know that $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in X$ and that $y \in B$, so by definition $x \in f^{-1}[B]$ and $y=f(x)$ shows that $y \in f[f^{-1}[B]]$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

$y$ in $f(A \cap f^{-1}(B))$ iff
exists $x$ in $A \cap f^{-1}(B))$ with $y = f(x)$ iff
exists x in A with $(f(x)$ in $B$ and $y = f(x))$ iff
$y$ in $f(A)$ and $y$ in $B$.

The second equation is an immediate corollary
of the first equation by setting $A$ to $X$.

Comment: I can't understand what did you do logically, how did you reach line 3?

Comment: why you don't say "iff" instead of "if"

Comment: @user715522  x in f ^{-1}$(B) iff  f(x) in B